# What is up with the [list] wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I was looking at [the wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5329258/18) for [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) today, and I must say I was thoroughly confused.

Most of the wiki talks about "list operators", which seem to be nothing more than the logical operators, and seem to bear absolutely no resemblance to "list" as it is used in most modern languages such as Python and Java.

For instance, take this quote:

> A list is denoted with logical operators. The specific syntax may vary based on the language and system being used. Common operators are semicolon (;), ampersand (&), double-ampersand (&&), or double-vertical-line (||).

I have never in all my days seen a list denoted with logical operators. Is this talking about nested logical statements (which I could see being called "lists" but in an entirely different sense than I am used to)?

The wiki resembled something more like I expected before [this edit in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5833040). However that edit was approved by 3 10k+ users (maybe only 5k+ at the time, but that's still some experienced people).

The wiki has also been edited since, [including by a 20k+ user](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5329258/16), in which they directly changed some logical operator stuff, but felt it was ok to remain in the wiki.

Thus, the evidence points to the wiki being correct as is, but I wonder how my understanding is so different from it.

Comment: I've got some doubts about the usefulness of such a broad tag at all.

Comment: Either I'm a total moron, or the only part of that tag wiki that is related to lists is the performance section...

Comment: WTF's going on with the links to semicolon, etc glyphs?? All the stuff up to **Performance** should be deleted forthwith as it seems to be talking about a sequence of logical expressions rather than a list data structure. Oh, and [tag:empty-list] needs a visit from Trogdor. BTW, I just edited the entry.

Comment: @KenY-N I was going to edit but yea, figured I'd do a sanity check here first

Comment: I'd bet some later editors were too timid to remove the confusing operators stuff (messing with stuff someone else edited, yadda yadda). That said, it's puzzling that that stuff got added in the first place.

Comment: Rolled it back to revision 15

Comment: @sideshowbarker sorry, I meant to before rev15, rev15 was the bad one, my bad, probably should've just said 14

Comment: @NickA that appears to be the most relevant one so it's now rolled back to #14.

Comment: @Jon thanks, you shouldnt have needed to

Comment: I wonder what the guy who wrote rev 15 and the 3 reviewers who approved it were drinking…

Comment: The confusion may have stemmed from Shell scripts, where [*command lists*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) are separated by `; & && ||` or newlines. These operators determine when and if the next command is executed, and therefore can be viewed as logical operators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is up with the [list] wiki?

Nothing anymore, the changes as discussed in the question [have been rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5329258/20).

Indeed, the logical operators have nothing to do with lists, as has been established in comments below the question. As [amon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362626/what-is-up-with-the-list-wiki#comment552750_362626):

> The confusion may have stemmed from Shell scripts, where [command lists](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) are separated by `;`, `&`, `&&`, `||` or new lines. These operators determine when and if the next command is executed, and therefore can be viewed as logical operators.

Comment: Huh, I had no idea those were called lists.  I always refer to them as command chains, because if one returns an unexpected value, that link breaks the chain.