# Why was this suggested tag wiki edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, specific-edit

A [recent tag wiki edit of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18660702) was rejected, and I'm trying to figure out why. The stated reason by the reviewers was

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

This is usually used for inconsequential changes, however I removed an entire section of code. I would expect the "harms post" reason if they disagreed with this change.

Perhaps they didn't see the code change, only the change further up, but I would expect better from reviewers in a 5K+ only queue, especially as I feel my comment was fairly descriptive.

Any ideas?

Comment: ... The one Java guy agreed with your change, the C++ and CSS ones did not :?

Comment: My guess: They didn't scroll down and since what they did see started off as, *"list can cover many types, depending on the language:"*, it looked like you're just changing an example in a list that isn't meant to be exhaustive anyway. (And thus an inconsequential change)

Comment: Better question: what the hell use is an "empty-list" tag? Who's an expert on empty lists?

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yea, I actually only came across it based on [this comment on my other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362626/what-is-up-with-the-list-wiki#comment552693_362626). I was hoping he'd make a burnination request, but this use of Java was bugging me so I figured I'd clean it up in the meantime.

Comment: I couldn't think of a suitable title so I didn't submit - "Make [`[tag:empty-list]`].empty() return `true`", perhaps? Actually, I was a little busy and forgot about it. Regarding your edit, I might have rejected it because the change is Java 8+-specific.

Comment: @KenY-N Maybe "Empty the question list of [empty-list]". Which part requires Java 8?

Comment: Generics are Java 8, aren't they?

Comment: @KenY-N Loooord no, that's Java 5 stuff: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html (though you did make me realize I had an error in my generics, it was in the original wiki as well, but I didn't fix it)

Comment: Oops, I learn something new every day! Most of my Java has been on Android to about v4, and they were never used there at all IIRC, so I just assumed they were not supported. (Anyway, we're straying off topic now)

Comment: The focus of the topic is on talking about (empty) ***lists***. Not about _interfaces_. In general, I fully endorse the principle of implementing list functions fully agnostic of particular concrete list-implementations (and your edit does that). However, it's an irrelevant angle here. Don't cloud the topic with concepts that are not ***specifically applicable*** to the topic. IMHO your suggested edit doesn't improve anything. (General tip: _Don't go on auto-pilot and apply rules blindly. Remember to take note of the context._)

Comment: @CraigYoung What? The original code with `LinkedList` is completely irrelevant, no one ever uses exceptions to check for list emptiness since `List.isEmpty()` has been there from the start (Java 1.2). So it makes sense to remove that example and make the `ArrayList` example use the interface instead. Also, [`LinkedList` has better alternatives for most of the use-cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/525036)

Comment: @DidierL What? Do you **really** not understand that point? It matters not the teensiest, tiniest, slightest little tot what particular concrete implementation of a list is better for any kind of implementation ***whatsoever!*** It's an utterly ***pointless*** tag about lists with no items. Getting high-and-mighty over what particular _flavour-of-the-week_ example should be used to illustrate a ***pointless*** topic is a complete waste of time. The edit did ***nothing*** to _improve_ the topic (hence why I would have also rejected it).

Comment: @CraigYoung oh, I totally agree that the `empty-list` tag is most probably useless. But as long as the tag exists, it should have a good tag description, and it should not give bad recommendations – and I am not talking about the type stuff but about the horrible non-compiling `try`/`catch` example. So from that perspective, it is a good edit and makes the description more accurate. An even better edit might be to entirely remove all code on this tag though.

Comment: @DidierL Point taken. A better edit would have been to delete the Java examples entirely. It's pointless to show an `isEmpty()` function that simply calls the `isEmpty()` member function of the list passed in. A more useful Java example would demonstrate a practical use of the existing function. The problem is that those are rare because very often it's not needed. Most examples of 'empty checks' that I've seen have been redundant because the code works on empty lists already. E.g. loops don't need an empty check, because empty lists don't enter the loop.

Comment: PS: It's interesting to note that the edit that created that bad Java code was passed by 3 votes to 2. It's a pity the 3 approvers of that edit weren't as critical as as the rejectors of @River's edit.

Comment: @CraigYoung I agree that deleting the Java code would've probably been a good option (and I considered it), but edits that *only* delete material tend to get rejected, so I don't think the "better" edit would've had better results. (In fact, I would expect worse)

Comment: @Cœur You've made the same edit. Including (1) unnecessary change of  `LinkedList` to `List` in the example types; (2) leaving the utterly pointless `isEmpty()` calling `isEmpty()` function. I still don't see this as a substantive improvement. Furthermore trying to push through an edit with the same deficiencies just wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having received no satisfactory answers<sup>1</sup>, I decided to go directly to the source and ask the reviewers themselves.

Apparently both of them failed to realized this was a *tag wiki* edit, not an edit to a post:

> You can't edit someone else's post to inform that something is wrong and/or should be implemented in different way. Your comment... [s]hould be placed below the post you edited.
>   <sub>[MateuszGrzejek](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41098223#41098223)</sub>

> I felt that the correction should have been pointed out in a comment on the answer first and allow the original responder to address it and any other issues in the answer.
>   <sub>[Kami](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41144326#41144326)</sub>

---

Both reviewers seemed to have been paying attention, as both had apparently read my comment.

I could see how someone working through the queue could make this mistake, as there is little to differentiate a [tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18660702) from a [regular edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5994258). Perhaps they should be made more easily distinguishable?

In any case, I will be prefacing my tag wiki edit comments with "TAG WIKI EDIT" from now on, in the hopes of avoiding this situation.

<sup><sup>1</sup>[One](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362780/why-was-this-suggested-tag-wiki-edit-rejected#comment554010_362780) was essentially "don't polish poo", which I feel doesn't apply to tag wikis as they are much, much more permanent than normal posts. [The other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362780/why-was-this-suggested-tag-wiki-edit-rejected/362882#362882) was [incorrect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362780/why-was-this-suggested-tag-wiki-edit-rejected#comment554309_362882).</sup>

Comment: I was one of reviewers who rejected the edit. I guess it should approved, because my reasoning was based on bad assumptions (I interpreted this edit as a regular edit, as you correctly guessed). My mistake, sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: Yup, I correctly assumed it was because of this confusion. So I resubmitted your edit with this clarification in the first words of the suggestion description: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41318957/revisions. Feel free to improve whatever change wasn't perfect.

Comment: You can now accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see ...

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,

Nope.

> easier to find,

Nope.

> more accurate

Not really.  Changing `LinkedList` to `List` in a list of examples is not an accuracy improvement.  Neither is the code change.

> or more accessible.

Nope.

> Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I would indeed characterize the wording change as superfluous.  The removal of one code example does not harm *readability*, and might not be best characterized as "superfluous", but overall, I think the chosen reject reason matches the proposed edit fairly well.

> I removed an entire section of code. I would expect the "harms post" reason if they disagreed with this change.

This looks like a judgment call to me.  I don't think the code change does much to help the tag wiki, but I could see a reviewer deciding that it doesn't rise to the level of actual harm.

I'm honestly unsure whether I would have voted to accept that edit, but had I chosen to reject it, I would have been likely to choose the same reason given by the two reviewers who actually did reject it.

Comment: The original code didn't `return false` for a non-empty list. The fixed code does. The edit comments clearly states this. Personally I'd view incorrect code->correct code as the *primary example* of "more accurate".

Comment: Also, I would argue reducing two examples down to a single, more general example improves readability, but the accuracy claim is really what disqualifies this reason.